# css / javascript fixed squares with other elements on access x / y with z-index

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox, css-position

I have a two part problem, if you look at the diagrams below you'll see I have a box with 9 boxes in it.  The outer box should be 80% (although in theory anything) but the boxes inside must always be spaced evenly and always 3 x 3.  Although this could be achieved with flex box the second part of this makes the task significantly more complex for me.  I then want to add 4 other elements at the centre point of each 4 boxes (top-right, top-left, bottom-right, bottom-left) which sit above them on a higher z-index.  With fixed positioning I could do this but this doesn't work because of the outer box percentage unknown due to variable screen sizes.

I'm not bothered if the answer is CSS only or Javascript Based or a combination or even flex box!

> **First part**

[image: 3 x 3 boxes in a box of unknown outer %]

> **Second part**

[image: positioned over top circles]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create this with pure CSS using **Flexbox**. To make perfect square that will stay square when you resize browser you can set height and width to same amount in vh units. Then you first create squares with margins and use `calc` to include that margin when you define widths. And in the end you add overlay with circles that will also be dynamic in vh units.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.content {
  height: 80vh;
  width: 80vh;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 2vh;
  flex: 0 0 calc(33.333% - 4vh);
}
.circles {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.top, .bottom {
  display: flex;
}
.circle {
  background: lightblue;
  height: 10vh;
  width: 10vh;
  margin: calc(10vh - 2vh);
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div> <div class="box"></div> <div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div> <div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div>
  
  <div class="circles">
    <div class="top">
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sheer class answer with flex-box **Nenad** absolutely perfect and concise!

Comment: Thank you, i am glad i could help.

Answer (score 0):

how about making one div-container with fixed width and height. Next into that container move two divs with absolute position. First one will handle 9 boxes, second 4 circles. The trick goes: because positions of div's inside are absolute, and theirs widths and heights get together are greater than containers size you'll see div with boxes and div with circles one on another. Than just scale it and set some z-index.

Comment: This is how I was approached it originally in my head but I like the elegance and simplicity of the flex box solution and backward compatible browsers aren't an issue. Thanks all the same.